# refresh particular element in jquery ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

This is my html code for showing category select options using php:

```
<select class="form-control" name="parent_category" id="parent_category">
 <option value="parent">Parent</option>
 <?php while ($parent = mysqli_fetch_assoc($parentresult)) : ?>
  <option value="<?=$parent['id'];?>"><?=$parent['category_name']; ?>
  </option> 
 <?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
```

this is jquery for category delete

```
function removecategory(cat_id){
 var removecategory = '';
 jQuery.ajax({
  url : '/multivendor/dashboard/parser/ajax.php',
  method : 'POST',
  data : {cat_id: cat_id, removecategory : 1},
  success : function(data){
   var result = JSON.parse(data);
   if ( result.status == "parentdelete" ) {
    location.reload(true);
   } else if( result.status == "childdelete"){
    $("#"+ cat_id).fadeOut("slow", function() { $(this).remove(); });
   }else{
    alert("something went row");
   }
  },
  error : function(){ alert("something went wrong");}   
 }); 
}
```

I am using reload to reload select with parent category

I want reload or refresh only select which gives me values of current database category.

Is this possible?

Comment: Replace a div where is the select with html(data)

Comment: Don't use `location.reload`. That refreshes the page completely, so any change made by your JavaScript, any data loaded via AJAX etc is completely destroyed, and the page loads again from the server. This somewhat defeats the point of using AJAX. Instead do something similar to how you do in the "childdelete" case where you change the related elements on the page itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, using clear AJAX. Create a div, which will contain the element you create:

```
<div class="select"> // the div will place where you want to put the select
</div>
```

the PHP file "get_select.php" goes as follows:

```
<select class="form-control" name="select_data" id="select_data">
    <option value='0'></option>
    <?php
      require_once("Connection.php");//here you put your connection to database

      $query = mysqli_query($link,"//link is my connection variable
      //all your mysql query
      ");
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
       echo "<option value=$row[row_name_database]>$row[alias_of_your_values ]</option>";
       }                    
    ?>
</select>
```

The index page has the following AJAX code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_select();//loading the document updates it
});

function load_select(){
var parameters = {"action":"ajax"};
$.ajax({
    url:'get_select.php', //we call our php file that calls the data
    type: "POST",
    data: parameters,
    beforeSend: function(object){
    },
    success:function(data){
        $(".select").html(data).fadeIn('slow');//we refer to our div by its class
    }
})
}

function removecategory(cat_id){
 var removecategory = '';
 jQuery.ajax({
  url : '/multivendor/dashboard/parser/ajax.php',
  method : 'POST',
  data : {cat_id: cat_id, removecategory : 1},
  success : function(data){
   var result = JSON.parse(data);
   load_select();//load the select with the desired elements
  },
  error : function(){ alert("something went wrong");}   
 }); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: can i refesh any html element with jquery ? i can do all that but i dont want to, because this refresh occur in every situation on my site, so i cant store all elements in many files

Comment: you can update any object you want with the information you want, if you want the same code to work on several pages, just copy the javascript code into a js file and refer to it in the document where you add it